# We have multiple repos having same package. IF we do yum install package, install from stable repo and yum install package-version install other repo

Tags: yum, rpm

We've got multiple custom-added yum repositories (on CentOS 6),  We have a package that is available on multiple repositories. It's named the exact same thing on two different repositories, call them Y and Z.. If  i say yum install package it should install from Y and if i say yum install package-ver it should install from package Z. Is it possible

Comment: Let us for a moment assume it is.  If you do that, then the next `yum update` wll pull the higher-numbered version from the other repository, and undo your work.  So could you tell us *why* you want to do this; ie, what are you actually trying to achieve?